# can't access wikipedia today's featured content using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, wikipedia-api

as stated in the title, I am trying to access Wikipedia's today's featured content, but only get an error as a response:

```
{
  type: 'https://mediawiki.org/wiki/HyperSwitch/errors/bad_request',
  method: 'get',
  detail: 'Invalid mm parameter',
  uri: '/en.wikipedia.org/v1/feed/featured/2023/3/7'
}
```

I am using their example code ([LINK](https://api.wikimedia.org/wiki/API_reference/Feed/Featured_content)):

```
// Get today's featured content from English Wikipedia

let today = new Date();
let year = today.getFullYear();
let month = today.getMonth() + 1;
let day = today.getDate();
let url = `https://api.wikimedia.org/feed/v1/wikipedia/en/featured/${year}/${month}/${day}`;

let response = await fetch( url,
    {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN',
            'Api-User-Agent': 'YOUR_APP_NAME (YOUR_EMAIL_OR_CONTACT_PAGE)'
        }
    }
);
response.json()
    .then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

with my data:

```
headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer 123456123456123456...123456',
            'Api-User-Agent': 'test (test@gmail.com)'
        }
```

my API key is a Personal API token:

[image: wikipedia_create_personal_access_token]

I execute everything with

```
node src/test.js
```

where

```
node --version
v18.14.1
```

someone knows, where my mistake is?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Don't use wiki api, but   `2023/3/7`  could it be that it's `2023/03/07` ?   The docs say -> `{YYYY}/{MM}/{DD}`   The error `'Invalid mm parameter'` would seem to indicate this.

Comment: @Konrad, yes, the error message is stated in the first code block (black background)

Comment: @Keith now that's so obvious! Thanks, that is in deed the answer. Could you please also post it as an answer so that I could accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use wiki api, but `2023/3/7` could it be that it's `2023/03/07`?

The docs say -> `{YYYY}/{MM}/{DD}` The error `Invalid mm parameter` would seem to indicate this be the case.

So a simple solution, you could maybe do this.

```
let year = String(today.getFullYear()).padStart(2,'0');
let month = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2,'0');
```